# Why is the return result of ExecuteExcel4Macro always False?

Tags: python, vba, excel-4.0

While using `ExecuteExcel4Macro` to run a Excel macro in Python, I always get the False result, here is the code executed:

```
import win32com.client

filename = r'E:\excel.xls'
xlApp = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
xlApp.visible = 1
xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filename)

strPara = xlBook.Name + '!Macro1()'
res = xlApp.ExecuteExcel4Macro(strPara)
print res

xlBook.Close(SaveChanges=0)
```

and the output of "print res" statement is: `False`

After I search the usage of `ExecuteExcel4Macro` on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa191494%28v=office.10%29.aspx), I get the following information:

> ExecuteExcel4Macro -- Runs a Microsoft Excel 4.0 macro function and then returns the result of the function. **The return type depends on the function.**

Then I get confused: since macro in Excel is always a "Sub procedure" and a "Sub procedure" in VBA has no return result, how can a Excel macro return a result? Then what does the False result in the above example stand for?

After that, I try `ExecuteExcel4Macro` within Excel(2003) by coding not in Python but in VBA:

```
Sub RunMacro()
    res = ExecuteExcel4Macro("excel.xls!Macro1()")
    MsgBox CStr(res)
End Sub
Sub Macro1()
    MsgBox "in Macro1"
End Sub
```

and the "res" string shown in `MsgBox` is the same: `False`

1.Why is the return result of `ExecuteExcel4Macro` always False?

2.What should I do if I want to run an Excel macro in Python and to get the exit status of the Excel macro function?

---

Updated at 2011.10.28:

```
Sub TEST()
    res = Application.Run(MacroToRun)
    MsgBox CStr(res)
End Sub

Function MacroToRun()
    MacroToRun = True
End Function
```

After I run TEST Macro in Excel 2003, I get this:

A dialog with the information "Error 2015".

Comment: Are you trying to run an actual Excel4 macro, or a regular (VBA) one?  The method you're using isn't intended for running VBA macros: check out Application.Run instead.

Comment: The ExecuteExcel4Macro function really isn't provided to run VBA macros, althought it actually can. Thank you for your advice, and I'll try Application.Run later. Thanks!

Comment: I've just tried the Application.Run method by replacing ExecuteExcel4Macro with Run in: (1) Python code above; (2）VBA code above, and the result I get was: (1) "-2146826273"; (2) "Error 2015". I don't konw what's wrong, maybe I should consider not to get the return result of the macro being run:)

Comment: As Joel pointed out, you need to make your macro a function if you want to get a return value.  This does work, so there must be something in your code which isn't quite right.  You could update your question with your current code.

Answer (score 0):

You may define Excel functions, not by starting with `sub` but with `function`:

```
Function Area(Length As Double, Optional Width As Variant)
    If IsMissing(Width) Then
        Area = Length * Length
    Else
        Area = Length * Width
    End If
End Function
```

This should return something. This something is the content of the variable named after the function (here `Area`).

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I think I've tried to define the VBA macro with 'Function' label instead, but I got not the return result of 'Function' labeled macro but the same False result.

Comment: Mmh, if your macro is the `Macro1` described above, no wonder you get nothing useful. Could you please provide us with the code generating the result you're looking for?

Comment: I have tried every possible syntax with the ExecuteExcel4Macro method. But it appears that even if a VBA UDF can be used in an XL 4 Macro Sheet with `=RETURN(UDF())` to return any non-object variant, it seems it is not possible to get the correct return from a UDF called with the ExecuteExcel4Macro method. The UDF can be called and it runs correctly (stepped into with VBE debug mode), but it always returns False.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a VBA UDF using this Excel 4 Macro with the ExecuteExcel4Macro method:

```
retval = Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro("EVALUATE(""Book1!some_UDF()"")")
```

The use of the Excel 4 Macro Function EVALUATE() won't allow you to step into the UDF named "some_UDF" in VBE debug mode as you could if you had called the UDF from an Excel 4 Macro (see Example).

I have also noticed that Application.Caller cannot be mentioned at all in the UDF, otherwise Excel crashes.

> Example

Excel 4 Macro Sheet with the following (cell $A$1 being a named "Macro1" via Name Manager):

```
$A$1: Macro1
$A$2: =RETURN(Book1!some_UDF())
```

Excel Worksheet in cell

```
$A$1: =Macro1()
```

As a conclusion, I suspect this Example to works correctly only because Excel uses its own Application.Evaluate to get the result of the VBA UDF (lets say integer 10), and then running the Excel 4 Macro as if it where:

```
$A$1: Macro1
$A$2: =RETURN(10)
```

Indeed, prior to the VBA era, in 1992, when there was only Excel 4.0 Macro Functions, `=RETURN(Book1!some_UDF())` could not possibly work, its inconceivable (not verified but I can't see how it could works...)

So to have exactly the same behavior in VBA only, the call would be:

```
retval = Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro("EVALUATE(" & Application.Run("Book_XL4M!test_10") & ")")
```

Answer (score 0):

Some additional information from the year 2020.
N.B.: I am using Excel Pro plus 2016
This comment is just here to save someone else the pain and lost time I have gone through.  This maybe obvious to some programmers but I didn't know nor could I find anything on the internet advising me of the problem/restriction.

After a lot of painful work I have discovered you cannot run ExecuteExcel4Macro within a function(UDF).  Also worked out you cannot call a sub that runs ExecuteExcel4Macro form within a function(UDF). It just ended the function at the ExecuteExcel4Macro and returned #Value! in the cell.  I did not have an error capture system running.  This may be the issue with the above problem but I'm not sure if there is a different result on older excel.
Background Info:
I have a cell I wanted to test if the user had changed the colour or if the conditional formatting had changed the colour.  I wanted to know what colour was showing on the screen.
I tried a function (UDF) but had an issue with .displayformat.  You cannot use .displayformat in a function.
So I thought I could use the Get.Cell(63,cell).  To do that I needed to use ExecuteExcel4Macro but it would not work in a function(UDF).  It would crash the function with Error2015.  However it did work in a macro by itself.
I was using a named range with a formula of =GET.CELL(63,INDIRECT("rc",FALSE)) for the conditional formatting and this worked without incident.

Some of the code I was using to test in a function(UDF).  After TempA was defined I would jump to Temp = ...

```
TempA = Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro("Sqrt(4)")

TempA = Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro("GET.CELL(42)")

TempA = "GET.CELL(63,HistorySheet!" & MyCell.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & ")"

Temp = ExecuteExcel4Macro(TempA)
```

The issue of ExecuteExcel4Macro in a function(UDF) may be obvious to some programmers but I didn't know nor could I find anything on the internet let me know of the problem/restriction. Hoping this will help someone in the future